# How to fix 'chrome not reachable' & 'DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' error in rasberrypie3 python

Tags: python, selenium, cron, chromium

I have two different cases of problems.
Basically, when I run the code with python in terminal on rasberrypie3, it works well.

But when I try to run with cron, it doesn't work.

1st case : don,t use headless chromium-browser.

2nd case : use headless chromium-browser.

```
#1st case
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
#options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get('target_url')
driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(some_id)
driver.quit()

#2nd case
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get('target_url')
driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(some_id)
driver.quit()
```

I expect that 'some_id' put in the id box.
But 1st case => `unknown error : DevToolActivePort file doesn't exist`
    2nd case => `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Chrome not reachable`